# Mandarin: 去 + xxx + 去了?

Tags: mandarin, topolect

Where we live I often here the construct 去 + 某某某 + 去了, for instance:

去打牌去了

去上厕所去了

去做饭去了

Can this kind of construct be used in Mandarin aswell?

Comment: If not Mandarin, where is this common?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be used that way, but nobody does that. Most people use one 去. Either before or after is fine.

Answer (score 2):

It can be used in Mandarin. However it sounds informal.

Answer (score 2):

It's an informal and redundant way of saying "去 + verb + 了", or "verb去了".

去打牌去了 (informal, redundant) --> 去打牌了 (formal, correct), or 打牌去了(formal, correct).

Answer (score 1):

Such usage is rare in modern generation. Often in spoken Chinese "去打牌了" suffices.